# Dynamically size Nativescript ContentView within ScrollView based on device height

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a Nativescript Vue component template defined as:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <ContentView ref="mapContainer" height="500" width="100%">
            <Mapbox
            accessToken="my access key"
            mapStyle="outdoors-v9"
            hideCompass="true"
            zoomLevel="10.2" , 
            latitude="51.949266"
            longitude="-12.183571"
            showUserLocation="true"
            disableZoom="true"
            disableRotation="true"
            disableScroll="true"
            disableTilt="true"
            @mapReady="onMapReady($event)">
            </Mapbox>
        </ContentView>
        <Label text="A test label"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When the component is mounted, I want to set the height of `mapContainer` to roughly 75% of the screen height. To do so, I have:

```
export default {
    name: "MyPage",

    mounted () {
        this.$refs.mapContainer.height = platform.screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs
    }

    ...

}
```

But this does nothing, and the `ContentView` remains at 500dp tall.

`height` is meant to be a setter, but I figure I'm missing a redraw (?) to get this change to take effect, but not sure how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the `ContentView` via refs, you must use `.nativeView` property.

```
this.$refs.mapContainer.nativeView.height = platform.screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs
```

Also you don't have to calculate the height but simply set the height in percentage (70%) instead of fixed value (500) Or use a GridLayout with 7 partition (7*).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. For some reason the Mapbox component requires a fixed height within a ScrollView otherwise it doesn't render.

Comment: What is the import path of platform? That would be great to specify. Thanks

Comment: Its different version to version, in V8.x you will have to import it from `'@nativescript/core/platform'` - https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/screen#mainscreen